# With AngularJS based single page apps hosted on premise, how to connect to AWS cloud servers

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Maybe this is a really basic question, but how do you architect your system such that your single page application is hosted on premise with some hostname, say mydogs.com but you want to host your application services code in the cloud (as well as database). For example, let's say you spin up an Amazon EC2 Container Service using docker and it is running NodeJS server.  The hostnames will all have ec2_some_id.amazon.com.  What system sits in from of the Amazon EC2 instance where my angularjs app connects to?  What architecture facilitate this type of app?  Especially AWS based services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the important aspects setting up the web application and the backend is to server it using a single domain avoiding cross origin requests (CORS). To do this, you can use AWS CloudFront as a proxy, where the routing happens based on URL paths.

For example, you can point the root domain to index.html while /api/* requests to the backend endpoint running in EC2. Sample diagram of the architecture is shown below.

[image]

Also its important for your angular application to have full url paths. One of the challenges having these are, for routes such as /home /about and etc., it will reload a page from the backend for that particular path. Since its a single page application you won't be having server pages for /home and /about & etc. This is where you can setup error pages in CloudFront so that, all the not found routes also can be forwarded to the index.html (Which serves the AngularJS app).

Comment: Thanks.  This is probably a bigger topic but how are deployments normally handled with EC2.  Do you end up deploying all the code at once to EC2 such that all instances have the same version.

Comment: When you setup autoscaling and load balancing after each deployment all the servers will get the latest version but not in a single go. There are couple of approaches to do deployments without down time. One such approach is using rolling updates. Another one is doing blue-green deployments.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to care about is the CORS on whatever server you use to host your backend in AWS.

**More Doc on CORS:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to have two separated instances. It is, an instance to serve your API (Application Program Interface) and another one to serve your SPA (Single Page Application).

For the API server you may want more robust service because it's the one that will suffer the most receiving tons of requests from all client instances, so this one needs to have more performance, band, etc. In addition, you probably want your API server to be scalable when needed (depends on the load over it); maybe not, but is something to keep in mind if your application is supposed to grow fast. So you may invest a little bit more on this one.

The SPA server in the other hand, is the one that will only serve static resources (if you're not using server side rendering), so this one is supposed to be cheaper (if not free). Furthermore, all it does is to serve the application resources once and the application actually runs on client and most files will end up being cached by the browser. So you don't need to invest much on this one.

Anyhow, you question about which service will fit better for this type of application can't be answered because it doesn't define much about that you may find the one that sits for the requisites you want in terms of how your application will be consumed by the clients like: how many requests, downloads, or storage your app needs.

[Amazon EC2 instance types](https://aws.amazon.com/en/ec2/instance-types/)